# PowerMock Java URL using EasyMock

Tags: java, easymock, powermock

I have the following code...

```
@Test
public void wrapSoapTest1() throws TransformerConfigurationException, IOException {
    RequestUtil r = new RequestUtil(SAMPLE_REQUEST_BEFORE.getBytes(),"");
    URL url = PowerMock.createNiceMock(URL.class);
    r.setXslUrl(url);
    EasyMock.expect(url.openStream()).andReturn(IOUtils.toInputStream(XSLT, "UTF-8"));
    Assert.assertEquals(SAMPLE_REQUEST_AFTER, new String(r.wrapSOAP()));
}
```

When I run this though I get the following error....

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: java/net/URLStreamHandler.openConnection(Ljava/net/URL;)Ljava/net/URLConnection;
at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:957)
```

Is there a way to mock a URL and send a custom string as the response?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `PowerMock` you must ensure that your test case is annotated with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`. Than you must tell `PowerMock` to prepare the `URL` class for the test (`@PrepareForTest({ URL.class })`) and you should use `PowerMock.expectLastCall()` instead of the `EasyMock` methods. At least you must put the mock into the replay mode.

This should work.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ URL.class })
public class SoapTest {
    @Test
    public void wrapSoapTest1() throws TransformerConfigurationException,
        IOException {
        RequestUtil r = new RequestUtil(SAMPLE_REQUEST_BEFORE.getBytes(),"");
        URL url = PowerMock.createNiceMock(URL.class);
        r.setXslUrl(url);
        url.openStream();
        PowerMock.expectLastCall().andReturn(IOUtils.toInputStream(XSLT, "UTF-8"));
        PowerMock.replay(url);
        Assert.assertEquals(SAMPLE_REQUEST_AFTER, new String(r.wrapSOAP()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it still didn't work, had to mock the URLConnection(?) I will post more info in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I have TestNG, PowerMock and EasyMock and only difference is that I had to add @PrepareForTest({ MyTestedClass.class }), in my case MyTestedClass is UrlScreenRequest.

```
    @PrepareForTest({UrlScreenRequest.class})
    public class UrlScreenRequestTest  extends PowerMockTestCase {
    ...
    @Test
    public void testValidatePermission() throws Exception {
      URL url=PowerMock.createNiceMock(URL.class);
      HttpURLConnection connection = createMock(HttpURLConnection.class);
      url.openConnection();
      PowerMock.expectLastCall().andReturn(connection);
      PowerMock.replayAll(url, connection);
      UrlScreenRequest request = new UrlScreenRequest(url);
      request.validatePermission();
      //validation
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My version looks like this...

```
private URL mockURL() throws IOException{
    final URLConnection mockConnection = PowerMock.createMock(URLConnection.class);
    InputStream i = IOUtils.toInputStream(XSLT, "UTF-8");
    EasyMock.expect(mockConnection.getInputStream()).andReturn(i);
    EasyMock.replay(mockConnection);
    final URLStreamHandler handler = new URLStreamHandler() {
        @Override
        protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL arg0)
                throws IOException {
            return mockConnection;
        }
    };
    return new URL("http://foo.bar", "foo.bar", 80, "", handler);
}
```

Comment: This works for us as well, see my solution if you dont want to change handler.